# @Inject failing when injecting in a @Stateless bean

Tags: java, dependency-injection, ejb, cdi

I'm working in a project with Java EE 7 and I need to inject a `javax.ejb.@Stateless` bean into another. Both beans have a similar structure:

```
@Stateless
public class OperationRepository extends GenericRepository<Operation> {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public OperationRepository() {
    }
    /*Implementation of abstract methods, getters/setters, etc*/
}

@Stateless
public class MenuRepository extends GenericRepository<Menu> {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Inject
    private OperationRepository operationRepository;

    public MenuRepository() {
    }
    
    /*idem OperationRepository*/
    
    public List<Menu> getMenuFromOperation(...) {
        // Do something where I need operationRepository
    }
}
```

The `GenericRepository<E>` is just an abstract class with some common methods and other abstract methods, doesn't matter here.

The problem is that in the `getMenuFromOperation()` method I get a NullPointerException. Debugging the code I realized that the injected `operationRepository` is null when requested in the method.

**Why does fail the injection point? what am I missing here?**

Just to make a little test, I injected manually by instantiating a default `OperationRepository` in the `MenuRepository` constructor, but in that case the `OperationRepository.entityManager` isn't injected (is null)

Thanks in advance for your answers.

## Edit #1

As requested by [John Ament](https://stackoverflow.com/users/577181/john-ament), here it goes:

1. All my code is in a single `jar` file. It's a Maven module that will be deployed together with a web module (a `war` package) in a **Glassfish Server 4.1**.
2. The `beans.xml` still doesn't exists yet, because the project isn't ready to be deployed (I didn't perform any integration test yet)
3. The `MenuRepository` is leveraged from a `@Test` class because I'm still developing `MenuRepository`.

The code for the test class is as follows:

```
public class MenuOperationRepositoryUTest extends BaseTestRepository {
    private MenuRepository menuRepository;
    private OperationRepository operationRepository;
    
    @Before
    public void initTestCase() {
        initTestDB();
        
        menuRepository = new MenuRepository();
        menuRepository.setEntityManager(em);
        operationRepository = new OperationRepository();
        operationRepository.setEntityManager(em);
    }
    
    @After
    public void finalizeTestCase() {
        closeEntityManager();
    }
    
    /*Some successful tests*/
    
    @Test
    public void showMenuFromOperation() {
        // Insert some dummy data into the test DB (HSQL)
        
        // This method needs the injected OperationRepository in MenuRepository
        List<Menu> menu = menuRepository.getMenuFromOperation(...);
        
        // Assertions
    }
}
```

And the BaseTestRepository is as follows:

```
@Ignore
public class BaseTestRepository {

    private EntityManagerFactory emf;
    protected EntityManager em;

    // This is a helper class that contains all the boilerplate to begin transaction 
    // and commit, it's used to insert data in the test DB
    protected DBCommandExecutor dbCommandExecutor;

    protected void initTestDB() {
        // sigeaPU is the name declared in persistence.xml
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("sigeaPU");
        em = emf.createEntityManager();

        dbCommandExecutor = new DBCommandExecutor(em);
    }

    protected void closeEntityManager() {
        em.close();
        emf.close();
    }
}
```

I think that's all I got so far. Let me know any clue you can get (or guess)

Comment: Create interfaces and `@Inject` by interface.

Comment: Did you try adding @LocalBean to your classes?

Comment: @Geinmachi, as I understand it, you can omit interfaces when the bean is local. Also I've seen other projects working with te same structure, I think that's not the case. Tell me if you need more info about how the project to get another posible problem.

Comment: @XavierDury, I just tried but the result is the same...

Comment: Can you please share the code that leverages `MenuRepository`?  Can you also share a little about your packaging structure.  Is this all within a single WAR?  What container are you deploying to?  What does your `beans.xml` look like?

Comment: As mentioned in Java EE's documentation, under [23.13 Configuring a CDI Application](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/cdi-basic013.htm#GJBNZ) and [25.1 Packaging CDI Applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/cdi-adv001.htm#CACDCFDE), you should provide a *beans.xml* file, for EJB modules or JAR files, in the META-INF directory, in order to enable CDI awareness.

Comment: That very same documentation stands that `beans.xml` is optional. However I tried with a file with just the `bean-discovery-mode="all"` but the result is the same.

Comment: `...In an implicit archive, CDI can only manage and inject beans annotated with a scope type.
For a web application, the beans.xml deployment descriptor, if present, must be in the WEB-INF directory.` You do not have a scope type on your Stateless EJBs. You should put beans.xml in both your jar and war.

Comment: @Franck, _"An implicit bean archive is an archive that contains some beans annotated with a scope type, contains no `beans.xml` deployment descriptor, **or contains a `beans.xml` deployment descriptor with the `bean-discovery-mode` attribute set to `annotated`**"_ . `@Stateless` bean are `@Dependent` scope by default. However I tried annotating the beans with the `@Dependent` annotation and with `beans.xml` with `bean-discovery-mode="annotated"` but nothing happened

Comment: How do you inject MenuRepository and in which bean? I suppose it is into  a bean packaged in your WAR.... So do you provide an explicit beans.xml in your war? or do you rely on the implicit mechanism again, in which case you have to explicitly specify the CDI scope on your target injected bean...

Comment: @Franck, if you look at **Edit #1**, you'll see that `MenuRepository` is invoked in a test case, and in the `@Before` method of `MenuOperationRepositoryUTest` it's instantiated, not injected (because I'm testing the class, not the injection mechanism) There's (yet) no `war` file, I'm performing pure `@Test` methods in a simple `jar`. Now I'm starting to worry about injection, because I need `MenuRepository` to work together with `OperationRepository` and I'm running into this problem, am I explaining correctly?

Comment: In this case it's not clear where you run into the problem with the null reference. In your test case I don't see any manual setting of OperationRepository into MenuOperationRepository which if you don't do won't happen by miracle (right?).

Comment: @Franck YES!!, that solved the problem, was missing to set the reference to `MenuRepository.operationRepository` by doing `menuRepository.setOperationRepository(operationRepository)` in the `@Before` method of the test class. Can you post your comment as an answer so I can check it as the correct one? I still wonder if my CDI configuration in allright, but I'll worry about that later on

Comment: Your configuration seems to be alright. What you're doing is very straightforward and should work without problem when you're ready to build your war module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're testing out of the CDI container you should also set your dependencies manually in the `@Before` method of the test class.

`menuRepository.setOperationRepository(operationRepository)`